# java:17: error: missing return statement

Tags: java

I wrote code to get a number from the user, then check whether the number is prime.

My code is:

```
import java.util.*;
public class hanoo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("please enter an integer number");
      int number = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println(num(number));
    } 

    public static String num(int number) {
      for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i != 0)
          return "it is prime";
        else
          return "it is not prime";  
      }         
   }   
}
```

It gives me a missing return statement error!

```
q1.java:17: error: missing return statement
   }
   ^
1 error

----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: What if your number is <= 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other answers havd correctly pointed out why you are getting the error, I feel obliged to point out that your code (and other answers here) will not correctly indicate whether the number is prime, or not. Try this instead:

```
public static String num(int number){

   for (int i = 2 ; i<number ;i++){
     if(number %i == 0) {
          // it has an exact factor.
          return "it is not prime" ;
     }
   }
   return "it is prime" ;
}
```

Comment: Edited and +1, earlier it said "it is not prime" in both return statements.

Answer (score 4):

Your function currently does not necessarily return anything. This is the case when `number` is smaller than or equal to 2. You should add a return statement outside of your for loop, so that the function will always return something.

Side note: The logic to decide whether a number is a prime or not is wrong. If the current function was valid, it would return `it is prime` if the number was odd and `it is not prime` if the number was even.

Comment: +1 for the pratical and simplier answer. Without need of code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If number variable is less or equal then for loop will not run. So return statement in for statement will not work. To fix your compilation error you should add return statement after for block. Your code will look something like this:

```
public static String num(int number){

   for (int i = 2 ; i<number ;i++){
      if (number%i!=0)
         return "it is prime";
      else
         return "it is not prime";
   }
   return "some message";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason your for loop not execute by condition failed, what is the return value??.so it is a error. try this..

```
public static String num(int number){
       String result = "";
       for (int i = 2 ; i<number ;i++){
         if(number%i!=0)
         result = "it is prime" ;
         else
         result =  "it is not prime" ;
      }
      return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return the else outside the for loop

```
public static String num(int number){

   for (int i = 2 ; i<number ;i++){
     if(number%i!=0)
         return "it is prime" ;

   }
   return "it is not prime" ; 
}
```

If the condition inside the if statement is met, then it will return "is prime" and the "not prime" will not be returned. If the if condition is never met in the loop, the "not prime" will be returned.

Comment: I think you mixed up your return statements. If 1 number is not divisible, it doesn't mean it is a prime. You have to check all numbers before telling that. So you will have to switch both your return statements and your if condition.

Comment: Tahts the way op has it, why the down vote. I'm not checking OP's logic, but his question of why he's getting the error.

Comment: I don't get how I changed to Op's logic. It remains the same.

Comment: No, for the OP, it would return prime if it wasn't divisible by 2 and not prime if it was. For you it will return prime if there is any number between 2 and number that cannot divide number and not prime if there is no such number.

Answer (score 0):

In java, a method which has defined `return` type can not end normally with out returning. You must `return value` from the method with out any implicit/explicit condition. A method like following is ok:

```
public int getInt()
{
   if(true)return 1;
   else return 0;
}
```

But a method which is returning as following:

```
public int getInt()
{
       if(true)return 1;
       else if(false)return 0;
}
```

will ask for return statement because after the second end condition, it can't evaluate the conditions other than the run time. For your case how ever, The problem is with the `for` loop. Whither it can go inside the for loop or not can't be evaluated at the compile time. So your program must pass the compile time ensuring that even if your `for` loop wasn't executed, it does return.

```
public static String num(int number){

   for (int i = 2 ; i<number ;i++){
     if(number%i == 0)  // <---- i have changed the condition
        return "it is not prime" ;


   return "it is prime";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to iterate up until the tested number n. It is enough to iterate only to sqrt(n). That is enough as both of the dividers cannot be greater than sqrt(n), because (a + sqrt(n)) * (b + sqrt(n)) > n for any a,b > 0.

A fiddle code to demonstrate that is at http://dew.apidesign.org/dew/#7545568